# How to set up Private Pods not supporting simulator

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I created a **private pod** that does not support the simulator, and now I run `pod lib lint` and I get an error:

```
-ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
```

Then I used `--verbose` and saw that it was compiled using the emulator:

```
CompileC /Users/xx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ctxhalwvkdrxongrjlngrlahubld/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o /var/folders/ mb/b7p9jyj93j75p9gl9m0c5yg00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20200609-54993-yfocd9-xxSDK/App/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /Users/xx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ctxhalwvkdrxongrjlngrlahubld/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o /var/folders/ mb/b7p9jyj93j75p9gl9m0c5yg00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20200609-54993-yfocd9-xxSDK/App/main.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

Obviously, my **private pods** do not support the simulator. Is there any setting to avoid compiling with the simulator?

I made some attempts, although `pod lib lint --skip-import-validation --allow-warnings` works, but `pod repo push MySpec xxSDK.podspec --skip-import-validation --allow-warnings` does not work.

**Private Pods** I created, using `:path =>'../'` works, but only for Devices.

Comment: Try clearing your derived data, clean project and build again

Comment: Thanks but not working

Comment: @Nullable were you able to find a solution? Facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @AaqibHussain  I haven't solved this problem at present, but I have bypassed the simulator by modifying the `xcodebuild` method in `validator.rb`. Because I can be sure that I will not compile with the emulator, I removed it. If you are not sure, it is best not to do this. `validator.rb` is under the `cocoapods` folder.